# How to respond with a stream using Grapevine server

Tags: c#, .net, grapevine

Is it possible, using Grapevine, to create an endpoint that returns a stream, such as a video?

In WCF I would create a function with a return type of Stream.  All Grapevine functions return IHttpContext.  Can I use something like "HttpContext.Current.OutputStream"?

Alternatively, I see something in the code:

```
public sealed class AdvancedHttpResponse
{
    ...
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a Stream object to which a response can be written
    /// </summary>
    public Stream OutputStream => _response.Response.OutputStream;
    ...
 }
```

How does one go about using this?

Comment: If you can stream with `HttpListener`, you can stream with Grapevine. As of 4.0, there is not built in implementation for it. You can, however, access the `OutputStream` from the `HttpResponseContext` using the property above, which is available to your route via `context.Response.Advanced.OutputStream`.

Comment: This question might have the answers you are looking for, or put you on a track to finding an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115422/httplistenerresponse-and-infinite-value-for-its-contentlength64-property

Comment: Yes, very useful.  Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to your question? If so, I'd be interested in your implemented. Post it as an answer here?